# Boot Windows from mSATA Dell Inspiron 7720

Tags: windows, windows-8, ssd, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron  7720, and it has a mSATA slot under a bottom cover. I installed a Crucial 32 GB mSATA in it, and it shows up in BIOS and Windows 8 as another drive (the "D" drive). However, in the BIOS, it does not show up as a selection when choosing a boot drive. I've already cloned by "C" drive to the mSATA drive using Acronis True Image, but I cannot figure out how to tell BIOS to boot from it. I realize it was meant as a caching drive, but I thought I could use it as a boot drive. Am I out of luck? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After much internet research I have come to the conclusion that the SSD drive is not bootable as it is currently impossible to set the drive as bootable in the BIOS.

Comment: Someone have actually managed to do it: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/p/19490832/21023607

Comment: BTW is it only the issue of the mSATA port or is it the same for the SATA port also?